# What is the best way to validate parameter from javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

Let's see some examples:

I've this function:

The function is waiting for one parameter(index), it's good to validate this way? My point is, the function is not throwing any error, if the parameter doesn't be an number, the function will simple not be used, it's bad(because anyone that is debugging this code will not see this error), but should i use "try and catch" everywhere?

ps: It's a not a validation to send to the server, it's only a validation that interact with user, so for example, if the user click in some button to set something(like color) this should do this, the only error here would occurs if someone changes via javascript the value from it, but it would only occurs in their browse...

```
/**
* @param Int index
*/
this.setDrawAttention = function (index) {
     if (lodash.isNumber(index) && !lodash.isNaN(index)) {
            this.drawAttentionIndex = index;
     }
};
```

Or this function would be better like this(using throw, but i don't like to have to use try catch everywhere... And why i need this? It will not be send to the server, and the error like i said before, only occur if the user changes this value via javascript, but this error will only show for him or for who are debugging this, but i don't need to do this...):

```
/**
* @param Int index
*/
this.setDrawAttention = function (index) {
     if (lodash.isNumber(index) && !lodash.isNaN(index)) {
            this.drawAttentionIndex = index;
     }
     else {
          throw {...};
     }
};
```

Or simple, like this(it will not be send to the server, and if someone try to put some other value, the error will be detected via browser, it's good to see if you're debugging...):

```
/**
* @param Int index
*/
this.setDrawAttention = function (index) {
     this.drawAttentionIndex = index;
};
```

Comment: I prefer the throw one. Sometimes I am checking real websites that are giving me an error, I am seeing from the throw part what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are exposing this as a public API, i.e., something that some other developer would use, then it is perfectly acceptable to throw an exception if they provide an illegal argument. I'd say that this is desirable over doing *nothing*, since it is immediately obvious to the user of the function that something went wrong.

Even if this is *not* a public API, it is still good practice, since it will also help *you* catch your mistakes.

Don't worry about catching it. You only catch an exception to wrap it in a different type and rethrow it (not commonly done in JavaScript) or if there is some conceivable way of recovering from the exception. Since there is no way to recover from the exception that is raised when you send in an illegal argument, you shouldn't have to catch it.